# Boost Shared Memory : the volume of a file has been externally altered and open file is not longer valid

Tags: c++, boost, vector, shared-memory

I'm using `Boost` `shared memory` to share vectors across different processes. However, on some occasions, the consumer of the shared memory throws up this exception:

> Unexpected exception: The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.

I have the proper `Synchronization` mechanism set in place. What could this error indicate?

---

**SOLVED** Size of the memory hadn't been properly allocated upon creation by one of the processes.

> When a shared memory object is created, its size is 0. To set the size of the shared memory, the user must use the truncate function call, in a shared memory that has been opened with read-write attributes

Source - [Boost shared memory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html)

Answer (score 1):

It means the volume for a file has been externally altered. Look for other processes writing the file.

In other words, it means you do not have proper synchronization in place.

Do you use [`bip::managed_mapped_file::grow`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_advanced_features.growing_managed_memory) by any chance? The documentation states it only allows offline growing.

Comment: I haven't used `bip::managed_mapped_file::grow`. Only 1 process is actually writing to the shared memory, The other is merely reading it, and `Boost Mutex` is applied to both the reading and the writing sections.

Comment: Can you show us exatly what you did? "Boost Mutex" is not a _thing_. Also, just serializing the critical sections pre-supposes you know what the critical sections are. Importantly, that should include opening/creating the mapping. It's time to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you want more help

Comment: Turns out, one of the several processes was the first to create the memory during a scenario, and the memory size hadn't been allocated, consequently it was created with size 0, and well, the rest followed.

Comment: we have encountered the same error when the file size of a mapped file is zero. On windows, boost 1.73 and up, using `bip::mapped_region`